Problem with CORS policy in React front end with FastAPI on the back trying to use Microsoft Single Sign-on
I'm trying to implement a SSO with react and FastAPI but I've been suffering because of CORS.
I tried multiple approaches, using middlewares, setting headers, etc. No sucess
I have this front on React:
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import './App.css';

function App() {
  
    const handleSubmit = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault(); // Evita que a página seja recarregada ao enviar o formulário
    
        // URL sem os parâmetros GET
    const url = 'http://localhost:5050/login';

    fetch(url,  
      {method: 'GET',
}).then((response) => {
        if (!response.ok) {
          throw new Error('Erro na solicitação');
        }

        window.location.href = response.json()
        return response.json();
      })
      .then((data) => {
        console.log('Resposta do servidor:', data);
        })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.error('Erro:', error);
      });
  };

  return (
    <div className="login-container">
      <h2>Login</h2>
      <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
                
        <button type="submit" className="login-button">Logar</button>
      </form>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;

I've done no changes to the file package.json apart from trying to set a proxy to my localhost:port, but it did not work.
In the fetch part I've tried all things I knew/could find, but no sucess.
Here's the FastAPI:
from authlib.integrations.starlette_client import OAuth
import uvicorn
import logging
from fastapi import FastAPI, Request
from starlette.middleware.sessions import SessionMiddleware
from fastapi.middleware.cors import CORSMiddleware

app = FastAPI()

logger = logging.getLogger('uvicorn.error')

app.add_middleware(
    SessionMiddleware,
    secret_key="?",  # You should use a strong, random key
)

app.add_middleware(
    CORSMiddleware,
    allow_origins=["*"],
    allow_credentials=True,
    allow_methods=["*"],
    allow_headers=["*"],
)

oauth = OAuth()
oauth.register(
    name='azure',
    client_id='SEU_CLIENT_ID',
    client_secret='SEU_CLIENT_SECRET',
    authorize_url='https://login.microsoftonline.com/SEU_TENANT_ID/oauth2/v2.0/authorize',
    token_url='https://login.microsoftonline.com/SEU_TENANT_ID/oauth2/v2.0/token',
    client_kwargs={'scope': 'openid email profile User.Read'}
)

@app.api_route('/login')
async def login(request: Request):
    redirect_uri = request.url_for('auth')
    return await oauth.azure.authorize_redirect(request, redirect_uri)

@app.get("/callback")
async def auth(request: Request):
    token = await oauth.azure.authorize_access_token(request)
    user = await oauth.azure.parse_id_token(request, token)
    return {"token": token, "user_info": user}

@app.get("/")
def hello_world_root():
    return {"Hello": "World"}

if __name__ == '__main__':
    uvicorn.run(app, port=5050)

The root route works just fine, that's my sanity check. And if I access the ip:port of my backend I get redirected to the SSO perfectly, so the Azure credentials are configured right.
Now, the issue:
You probably noticed I have two Middlewares on the code, I've tried both separately, I believe configuring CORSMiddleware properly would help, but if I don't use Starlette's I get:
"session" in self.scope
AssertionError: SessionMiddleware must be installed to access request.session
I don't know what to do in this part. I don't know if solving this will already solve the main error:
http://localhost:5050/login' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.
I would appreciate some help here.
Regards

I added the below lines in the App.js code to fix the CORS issue.
event.preventDefault();
window.location.href = 'http://localhost:5050/login';


event.preventDefault(); stops the default form submission, which usually reloads the page or redirects to another URL. This allows you to handle the submission.

window.location.href sets the browser's current URL to http://localhost:5050/login. Executing this line of code will redirect the user to the specified URL.


Code :
frontend/App.js :
import React from 'react';
import './App.css';
function App() {
    const handleSubmit = (event) => {
        event.preventDefault(); 
        window.location.href = 'http://localhost:5050/login';
    };
    return (
        <div className="login-container">
            <h2>Login</h2>
            <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
                <button type="submit" className="login-button">Logar</button>
            </form>
        </div>
    );
}
export default App;

backend/main.py :
import jwt
from authlib.integrations.starlette_client import OAuth
import uvicorn
import logging
from fastapi import FastAPI, Request
from starlette.middleware.sessions import SessionMiddleware
from fastapi.middleware.cors import CORSMiddleware
import httpx

app = FastAPI()
logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO)
logger = logging.getLogger('uvicorn.error')

app.add_middleware(
    SessionMiddleware,
    secret_key="?",  
)
app.add_middleware(
    CORSMiddleware,
    allow_origins=["*"],
    allow_credentials=True,
    allow_methods=["*"],
    allow_headers=["*"],
)

oauth = OAuth()
oauth.register(
    name='azure',
    client_id='<clientID>',
    client_secret='<clientSecret>',
    server_metadata_url='https://login.microsoftonline.com/<tenantID>/v2.0/.well-known/openid-configuration', 
    client_kwargs={'scope': 'User.Read openid email profile'},
    httpx_client=httpx.AsyncClient()  
)

@app.get('/login')
async def login(request: Request):
    try:
        redirect_uri = request.url_for('callback')
        logger.info(f"Redirect URI: {redirect_uri}")
        return await oauth.azure.authorize_redirect(request, redirect_uri)
    except Exception as e:
        logger.error(f"Error in /login: {e}")
        return {"error": str(e)}

@app.get('/callback')
async def callback(request: Request):
    try:
        token = await oauth.azure.authorize_access_token(request)
        logger.info(f"Token response: {token}")
        access_token = token.get('access_token')
        id_token = token.get('id_token')  
        if access_token:
            if id_token:
                user = jwt.decode(id_token, options={"verify_signature": False})
                logger.info(f"User info: {user}")
                return {"access_token": access_token, "user_info": user}
            else:
                logger.error("ID token not found in the response")
                return {"access_token": access_token, "error": "ID token not received"}
        else:
            logger.error("No access token found in the response")
            return {"error": "No access token received"}
    except Exception as e:
        logger.error(f"Error in /callback: {e}")
        return {"error": str(e)}

@app.get('/')
def hello_world_root():
    return {"Hello": "World"}

if __name__ == '__main__':
    uvicorn.run(app, host='localhost', port=5050, reload=True)

backend Output :

I logged in using the URL below, and got the access token and user_info as shown.
http://localhost:5050/login


frontend  output :
I logged in and got the access token and user_info on the frontend, as shown below.




I can't express how grateful I am, Thank you!
